# At Least One bit in int num is 0

Tags: c

Trying to create a method that returns a 1 if the input int num has a zero in it using C without using if-else statements and using the bottom bitwise and boolean operators.

i tried this so far:

```
int hasAZero(int num){
 return !(num && 1);
}

Bitwise AND (c = a & b) – c has 1s in the places where both of the    corresponding bits in a and b are 1.
Bitwise OR (c = a | b) – c has 1s wherever at least one of the corresponding bits in a and b is 1.
Bitwise XOR (c = a ^ b) – c has 1s wherever one and only one of the corresponding bits in a and b is 1.
Bitwise NOT (c = ~a) – c is a, with each bit inverted, else c is 0.
Right shift (c = a >> b) – c is a, with each bit moved lower b places.
Left shift (c = a << b) – c is a, with each bit moved higher b places.
Boolean AND (c = a && b) – c is 1 if both a and b are non-zero.
Boolean OR (c = a || b) – c is 1 if either a and b are non-zero.
Boolean NOT (c = !a) – c is 1 only if a is 0.
```

Comment: Well `num && 1` is always going to be non-zero , so the logical inverse will always be zero.  Not very useful.  Why not just use `~num != 0`.  If you don't want to use `!=` then you can use `!!~num` instead.

Comment: !!~num uses only those ops

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for a 0 *bit*, right? Not a decimal digit like Keno's answer is about?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "has a zero in it"?  Give some examples of numbers that satisfy this property, and some that don't. You have written `&& 1` (meaning "...and true") which is not a bitwise operation.  Think about what you are trying to test, and how you would test for it in real life.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int hasAZero(int num) {
    return ~num != 0;
}
```

If `num` contains a zero bit, then its bitwise complement will contain a `1` bit and will be non-zero.  If it does not contain a zero bit, then its complement will be zero.

If you don't want to use `!=` then you can use `!!~num` instead as rpattiso pointed out (I wasn't clear is comparisons were allowed), i.e.:

```
int hasAZero(int num) {
    return !!~num;
}
```

Comment: Negative values would seem to pose problems. Should the bitwise operations not be limited to unsigned values?

Comment: @David Unsigned would probably be preferable, but I think bitwise complement should work on signed integers as well.  The only time this function should return false is if `num` is all `1`s, i.e. `-1` (or, for unsigned, it would be `0xffff....`).  I guess you could refer to it as `~0`.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to check if there is a zero in a whole integer or 'string' of numbers? E.g. 13590 <-- 0 at the end.

To do this, you need to check each digit using a loop and see if that digit is equal to zero. Here's one way of doing it.

```
int hasAZero(int num) {
    int val = num;

    while (val >= 10) {
        if ((val % 10) == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        val = val / 10;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for a 0 bit in the entire `int`, so this answer won't help.

Comment: @Tom Oh, well I guess I didn't fully understand his question.